# How to change scroll bar size in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How to change scroll bar size in Windows 7?

Comment: Increasing the DPI will increase everything size (including scrollbar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on desktop and select Customize. Click on Window Colors and then Advanced settings. In he drop-down list choose scrollbar (or click on the scrollbar in the picture) and finally change the size.

(Sorry if any comand is differently named - I'm not using an english version of Windows).

Addendum:

Personalize is the word in the USA version as opposed to Customize. Click on Window Color>Advanced Appearance Settings> Under 'Item' select Scrollbar.

Comment: You had it close enough. :-)
It's "personalize" instead of "customize".

Answer (score 3):

Go to Start > Run, and type Regedit.

Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control panel > Desktop > WindowsMetrics.

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
>
> "ScrollHeight"="-355"
>
> "ScrollWidth"="-355"

Values are expressed in [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip) and must be negative, as explained on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938237.aspx).

Comment: An explanation of what -355 means would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way but it involves you using `cmd` and replacing system files. If I'm right you are trying to modify the scrollbar.

You can take the `explorerframe.dll` from Windows 8. Come back to Windows 7 and open `CMD` and type:

- `cd windows`
- `takeown /f exploreframe.dll`
- Then go to `C:/windows/system32`
- Look for `explorerframe.dll`
- Back it up and then replace the Win 8 dll into the `system32` directory
- Restart

If you wanted to, you could try and replace the explorer.exe just replace the explorer.exe instead of the dll one in the `cmd`.