# Advanced appearance settings [Windows 7 or later]

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-8.1

On Windows XP, to change an advanced appearance setting (such as the system size of scrollbars) I would:

```
* Right-click the desktop and select Properties
* Select Appearance > Advanced
* Set Item to "Scrollbar" and then set the Size
```

[image: Windows XP display properties]

Where does one find the equivalent settings page in Windows 7 and Windows 8.1?

Comment: Looks like this question (http://superuser.com/questions/120120/how-to-change-scroll-bar-size-in-windows-7) is related...just checking on 7 and 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to change scroll bar size in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/120120/how-to-change-scroll-bar-size-in-windows-7), and related (showing the dialog no longer exists in 8+) [Is it possible to customize Windows 8.1 colors similarly to how it was since Win95 in the “Advanced Appearance Settings”?](http://superuser.com/questions/1121003/is-it-possible-to-customize-windows-8-1-colors-similarly-to-how-it-was-since-win?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Yes, looks like those two unrelated questions cover it, thanks. Weird that Microsoft would hide these settings under the `Windows Color` option in Windows 7 and remove them entirely in Windows 8.1. Do you want to answer it with those two questions or shall I just delete the question?

Comment: @magicandre1981: The suggested duplicate is neither an exact duplicate (it refers to colour and does not mention Windows 7) nor complete (as it mentions Windows 8.1 only). See the comment from OP above. Suggest either answer the question, referencing the two questions, or else ask the OP to delete.

Comment: @AlainD both ask how to open this Advanced appearance settings dialog, so they are both the same

Comment: @magicandre1981: You have a point, but it is not an "exact duplicate". The answer refers to Windows 8.1 and suggests installing a 3rd party utility which is not required on Windows 7. Someone looking for changing the scrollbar size on Windows 7 may find this question, but has no hope of finding the "same" question you suggest. I think the problem is the tag line `This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.` which appears under the mark as a duplicate. This is not right and something like `This question is related` that would be closer to the truth.